# Understanding normalization of tables in a simple cms

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a simple cms-application using php and sql with mysql as a database. I am having trouble with how I should organize tables in this system and what the php code should look like when selecting and inserting data into them.

In the cms I am working on the user can write articles and publish and upload an image attached to this article

So far my main concern has to do with two tables. The first is article which looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (

    `id` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `headline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `story` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `published` datetime NOT NULL
    
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here is the other, image:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image` (
    
    `id` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `insert_id` int NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int NOT NULL,
    `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (insert_id)
    REFERENCES cms_article (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES cms_user (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Am I on the right track or not?

Now, I know some SQL but I am not so good when it comes to normalization of tables in a database. I can imagine I must create a table called something like `tbl_article_image` in which I store the `id` of the article and image before posting. But how would this process look like in a php and sql way ? I don't know how I should work with php in a situation like this? One must obviously first check if an image exists or not in the table before the user insert it.

I am a little confused at the moment. But I hope there is someone here that can show me tip on how this is done in the real world out
there. I've got to learn this since I am working against a time frame.

What is wrong with my sql-code in this php function ? It shows an error like "near ?"

```
private function user_image_exists($insert_id) {
            
            $return_value = FALSE;
            
            $sql = "SELECT insert_id,user_id, COUNT(*) FROM " . 
            "image WHERE " . 
            "insert_id = ? AND user_id = ?";
            
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql); $stmt->bindParam(1,$insert_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);$stmt->bindParam(2,$this->user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            if ($stmt->rowCount() !== 0) {
                
                $return_value = TRUE;   
                
            }       
            
            return $return_value;
        
        }
```

I am trying to check if an image already exists in the table cms_image. I don't know if I am doing this the right way?

Am I still on the right track? Any help and tip is very much appreciated.

Please help me.

Comment: You should not be using Systems Hungarian Notation in databases (or anywhere, really), so don't use object name prefixes like `tbl_` - just do `CREATE TABLE articles` **not** `CREATE TABLE tbl_article`.

Comment: Another tip: don't use ambiguous column names like `id` - because it makes it very hard to follow a query that uses a `JOIN` if you're doing equi-joins on identically named columns - use names like `articleId` (or `article_id`) instead.

Comment: You need to add `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to your database tables.

Comment: Sorry, I, missed that out. I forgot about foreign keys. I have just started.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_cms_image` (
 
 `id` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `insert_id` int NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 
 FOREIGN KEY (insert_id)
 REFERENCES tbl_article (id)
 ON DELETE CASCADE,
 
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
 REFERENCES tbl_cms_user (id)
 ON DELETE CASCADE

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: What is Systems Hungarian Notation?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: Also, you don't need that many backticks in your DDL.

Comment: @ingmarleifsson It's awful and made the less-sexy-parts of the software industry insufferable for _sophists of software aesthetics_ like myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. I will move on from Hungarian tables :)